# How to create a detachable toolbar kind of thing

Tags: jquery

I am developing a web based application where I need to have a detachable toolbar kind of thing. This way user would be able to move the toolbar to somewhere else in the browser while working.

A site already has this kind of functionality. Here is a snapshot

http://skitch.com/neerajdotname/dai12/neeraj-singh-flavors.me

What jQuery plugin might help me get that kind of detachable window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check

***EasyDrag jQuery Plugin***

http://fromvega.com/wordpress/2007/07/14/easydrag-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

You might try jQuery UI's [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/).